# What does this function in this context really do?

Tags: python, lambda

I was analysing code as I had some free time and thought  could learn something new! This was from a Binary to Denary converter code I found.
But I have been bouncing it around in my head for almost the past 2-3 days now but I absolutely can't bring myself to what this statement/function/line does or means?

```
lambda b: str(int(b, 2))
```

I think the 'b' in (b, 2) means Binary?

I researched and found that lambda is a function to 'call in' Anonymous functions or functions that have no name. Is that correct?

What does 'b:' mean? Is that also Binary or maybe a 'sub name' within lambda?

Also what does

```
str(int(b, 2))
```

mean? I know thats the code that converts binary to denary but how does it exactly work?

I am very curious to find out! Hopefully someone will be able to help me get my head around this!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a great question about lambdas: [Why are Python lambdas useful?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890128/python-lambda-why)

[int() from the docs:](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int)

> int(x, base=10)
>
> Convert a number or string x to an integer, or return
> 0 if no arguments are given. If x is a number, it can be a plain
> integer, a long integer, or a floating point number. If x is floating
> point, the conversion truncates towards zero. If the argument is
> outside the integer range, the function returns a long object instead.
>
> If x is not a number or if base is given, then x must be a string or
> Unicode object representing an integer literal in radix base.
> Optionally, the literal can be preceded by + or - (with no space in
> between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of
> the digits 0 to n-1, with a to z (or A to Z) having values 10 to 35.
> The default base is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2-36. Base-2, -8,
> and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with 0b/0B, 0o/0O/0, or
> 0x/0X, as with integer literals in code. Base 0 means to interpret the
> string exactly as an integer literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8,
> 10, or 16.

Comment: Yes, it will be in base 2. The call will convert it to base 10.

Answer (score 2):

`b` is the *argument* to the `lambda` function:

```
lambda b: ....
```

The first part before the `:` defines the arguments for the anonymous function, this one defines just `b` just like a function signature would:

```
def binary_to_int(b):
    # ...
```

It could have been given another name too:

```
lambda anothername: int(anothername, 2)
```

It is bound to the argument you pass to this lambda:

```
binary_to_int = lambda b: int(b, 2)
result = binary_to_int('010101')  # so b is bound to '010101'
```

The function returns the result of the function `int(b, 2)`, which interprets a string first argument as an integer in base 2 (binary):

> If *x* is not a number or if base is given, then *x* must be a string or Unicode object representing an integer literal in radix *base*. Optionally, the literal can be preceded by `+` or `-` (with no space in between) and surrounded by whitespace. A base-n literal consists of the digits 0 to n-1, with `a` to `z` (or `A` to `Z`) having values 10 to 35. The default *base* is 10. The allowed values are 0 and 2-36. Base-2, -8, and -16 literals can be optionally prefixed with `0b/0B`, `0o/0O/0`, or `0x/0X`, as with integer literals in code. Base 0 means to interpret the string exactly as an integer literal, so that the actual base is 2, 8, 10, or 16.

Comment: This answer has answered all my questions! Thank you very very much! I can calm down now! @Martijn Pieters

Comment: @PythonBeginner: Sorry, you can mark only *one* answer as accepted, not all of them. Glad you found all answers to be of help though!

Answer (score 1):

`b` in this case is the argument to your anonymous `lambda` function. However, judging from what the anonymous function does, it seems pretty clear that `b` should be a binary string.

I think the easiest way to understand what the anonymous function does is through an example.

```
>>> b = '101'
>>> int(b, 2) # converts a binary string to base-10.
5
>>> str(int(b, 2))
'5'
```

The anonymous function converts a binary string to [base-10 integer](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int), and then converts that integer back to a string. To actually use the anonymous function, you could do something like the following:

```
>>> fn = lambda b: str(int(b, 2))
>>> fn('10001')
'17'
```

Or in de-anonymized form:

```
>>> def convertFromBinary(b): return str(int(b, 2))
>>> convertFromBinary('10001')
'17'
```

Comment: so i was correct in saying 'b' means Binary? or a similar concept?

Comment: @PythonBeginner: `b` does not mean binary, `b` is just the name of the argument passed to the anonymous function. However, the function expects that `b`'s *value* will be a binary string.

Comment: Ahhh so 'b' is the name of arguement?

Comment: @PythonBeginner: yes exactly, check out the example of a de-anonymized version of the function I just posted.